# How to remove unused frameworks and libraries form Phonegap iOS project?

Tags: xcode, ios5, cordova, phonegap-plugins

In an empty Phonegap/Cordava iOS project, there are about 10 linked libraries and frameworks (MediaPlayer, AddressBook, etc). I am using only Core Location Framework and when I try removing the others, the build fails. How do I remove the the plugins and frameworks which are not necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to remove them in your "YourAppName/Supporting Files/Cordova.plist". When you open the file in Xcode you will see a Dictionary "Plugins". You can remove unused Frameworks there by deleting the Strings in the Dictionary.

Comment: I deleted the Contacts Plugin entry in the .plist file and removed AddressBook and AddressBook UI frameworks from Linked frameworks and libraries section. Now, I am facing linker errors.

Comment: oh really, Im sorry about that, I havent encountered these problems yet.

Comment: Looks like I resolved that linker issue by doing a Clean and Build. Thanks :)